# How to show MessageBox with pygtk?

Tags: python, gtk, messagebox

In gtk/python, what is the equivalent of MessageBox?

Comment: It should be noted Pygtk is getting replaced with `gi.repository` Gtk bindings, these answers may not work well for new projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [gtk.MessageDialog](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkmessagedialog.html).

Example:

```
parent = None
md = gtk.MessageDialog(parent, 
    gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, 
    gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Download completed")
md.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this tutorial about message dialogs with PyGTK :

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/dialogs

In addition, you can [read the documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmessagedialog.html) about the MessageDialog class.

Comment: not surprsing for such an old answer but both links are now dead...